# oracle procedure giving ORA-00905: missing keyword

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to create a generic procedure to synchronize sequences.
I want to call the procedure and pass name of table, column and sequence but my procedure won't run due to an error.

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INCREMENT_SEQ(table_name in varchar2 , id_column in varchar2 , sequence_name in varchar2) 
AS
current_value  number;
seq_val number := -1;
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select max(' || table_name || '.' || id_column || ') into current_value  from ' || table_name ;
WHILE current_value  >= seq_val
LOOP
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || sequence_name || '.nextval into seq_val from dual';
end loop;
end;
```

when I run the script I'm having the following error:

> Error at line 2
>
> ORA-00905: missing keyword
>
> ORA-06512: at "TGC100_DEV.INCREMENT_SEQ", line 6
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1
>
> Script Terminated on line 16.

But I have no idea how to solve. Any advice would be helpfull.

Comment: The `INTO` clause cannot be inside the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should put `INTO` clause outside the query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INCREMENT_SEQ(table_name in varchar2 , id_column in varchar2 , sequence_name in varchar2) 
AS
current_value  number;
seq_val number := -1;
begin
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select max(' || table_name || '.' || id_column || ')   from ' || table_name into current_value;
WHILE current_value  >= seq_val
LOOP
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || sequence_name || '.nextval from dual' into seq_val;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Hi, @LalitKumarB, i don't understand, i think it's fixed for two execute immediate, please can you be more specific? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. This is the reason it is better to have the dynamic query formed as a variable to avoid confusions.

Comment: Yes, i see. I also prefer use dynamic sql, like you show above.

Answer (score 2):

> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select max(' || table_name || '.' || id_column || ') into current_value  from ' || table_name ;

It is syntactically incorrect. The **INTO** clause should be outside of **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** statement.

Something like,

`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'your SQL statement'  INTO variable USING value;`

**UPDATE** It is better to have the dynamic SQL as a variable to avoid confusions with so many single quotes and concatenation in the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement itself.

The other answer by Aramilo was posted before my answer, but I got confused to see the INTO clause already outside the statement.

For developers, it is always a good practice to first check the dynamic SQL using **DBMS OUTPUT** before actually executing it. Thus, it saves a lot of time to debug the whole bunch of PL/SQL code. Once confirmed that the dynamic SQL formed is correct, remove the DBMS_OUTPUT and execute the PL/SQL code.